# Custom columns in BootstrapVue table

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with `b-table` component in `bootstrap-vue`,

my array with items looks like this:

```
[{
    id: 1
    name: "Test",
    phone: 555-111-666,
    address: "Some address",
    //etc...

}]
```

and here i have two questions,

for the first, how to set custom columns names instead of this in object above? `b-table` right now, get columns names like in the object because i use `:items=myArray`? How to set custom columns names?

and for the second, I do not want to show all data in column what is in my object, how to show in table only `name` and `address` instaed of show all of the data?

and for third, how to add another custom column with e.q. icon istead of value from object?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `fields` prop, and supply an array of field objects you want to display.
The `key` will determine which property from your object it gets the data from, and the `label` will be what is displayed in the header.
You can also add virtual fields here, with a `key` that doesn't exist in your object.
You can then use slots to display some custom data in that column.

Here's some reference from the docs if you need more info.

Fields ref: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#fields-column-definitions

Custom data: https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-data-rendering

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "Test 1",
          phone: "111-222-333",
          address: "Some address"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Test 2",
          phone: "444-555-666",
          address: "Another address"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Test 3",
          phone: "777-888-999",
          address: "Questionable address"
        }
      ],
      fields: [{
          key: "name",
          label: "Full Name"
        },
        {
          key: "address",
          label: "User Address"
        },
        {
          key: "custom_column",
          label: "Custom Column"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template #cell(custom_column)>
      <b-icon icon="question-circle"></b-icon>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```